# Google Picker shows just a blank page

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I'm trying to develop javascript application which would allow user to select files from their Google drive,and then pass IDs of selected files to  PHP backend and download them to  my server.

For selecting files I'm using Google Picker, and I could use it normaly for a few days but suddenly It stopped to work. When  i click and try to open Picker dialog, loadPicker() function pass without any error reported by firebug but i get only blank iframe. I have tested it on several computers with several various browsers, all with the same result

First I was thinking that I've put wrong API key, but every time I try to load picker  that attempt is properly loged inGoogle API Console statistic pages, altrought every time i get just a blank screen. I have also tryed to make a new application an just copy/paste Google Picker hello world app source code from Google documentation, but I'm still getting just a blank page.

Any suggestions why this is happening? Is it possible that Google blocked Picker service for my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as disscussed at [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-picker-api/google%2420picker%2420blank%2420page/google-picker-api/icmqEUva2q8/0Rqe-Eh4PxsJ) it was a bug on Google side, it should'nt happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem too, while the picker was working correctly few days ago. I found the reason : in the meantime i had to create a Service Account key for other purposes (access to Google Apps Script apis). Using the clientId of the Web Application Key was causing a picker window with title and buttons but "No files found" inside, while my folder parent Id didn't changed.... I replaced the clientId by the one of the Service Account key, and it solved the issue. Good intuition.

Comment: Finally, it seems that was not the root cause. I had to go back to Web Application Key to get it work, after having had a "Invalid_client" message from Google later. Very strange. But seems there is a limited expiration time for a given token..

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. I can't beleive I spent almost two hours trying to figure the issue. In case you've tried everything expect closing the developer tools, please do that.

The file picker won't show unless the developer tools is closed.